# How to retrieve access tokens without AdalJS?

Tags: azure-active-directory, access-token, sharepoint-online, adal, adal.js

I registered an application in Azure AD.

How can I get access tokens Programmatically without using AdalJS library in JavaScript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the implicit grant flow manually.
You can see some basic documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#single-page-application-spa.

You'd authenticate the user by redirecting them to sign in, for example `https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=your-client-id&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&nonce=abcdef`.

Of course you'll need to replace values with your corresponding values.
And generate a unique nonce for each request.

Once the user comes back, you'll need to grab the `id_token` from the fragment and decode it to get the user info.
Then you can acquire access tokens for APIs with a hidden iframe with a very similar URL as before, but this time with `response_type=token&prompt=none&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F`.
Replace the resource with the resource URI/id that you want a token for.
Then you will have to listen for the URL change of the iframe and grab the access token from its fragment when it returns successfully (or parse the error in case authentication fails).

ADAL.JS hides a lot of this complexity from you so I'd strongly advise using it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me, so I use ADAL. I added script on my page using ScriptLink custom action and acquire token there. WHen adal adds iFrame with the link, I redirect there and it navigates me back to my page with parameters in hash (url), so my script retrieves token from urls hash.